# Is a delegate in Objective-C basically a class full of event listeners?

Tags: objective-c, delegates

Is a delegate in Objective-C defined as a class full of event listeners for an object?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by events. `NSEvent` and `UIEvent` are specifically used for user interaction events - these may or may not be handled by delegates.

Answer (score 6):

A delegate is merely an object that another object can use to query or customize behavior;  nothing more, nothing less.  No event handlers involved.   It is a pattern that is used to avoid the massive tangle of subclassing that you often see in other object oriented UI kits.

For example, instead of subclassing NSWindow to provide custom behavior on resize, you merely implement a few methods on a class somewhere and use an instance of that class as the delegate.   Since such implementation is typically dependent on control or model layer information, it is much more natural to use a control layer class as the delegate, not subclass NSWindow, and not pollute the view layer objects with control layer functionality.

Under the covers, delegates are dead simple.  When resizing, an NSWindow merely asks the delegate "Do you respond to the method `windowWillResize:toSize:` and, if it does, calls it at the right time;  nothing beyond straight objc_msgSend() about it.

Answer (score 0):

That may be one way to think of it, though not completely accurate. A delegate is responsible for handling callbacks for a given object. These may be events, they may not be.

Comment: So any method that is returning a value of some sort?   Is it usually used to return the state of an object?

Comment: No. Take the tableView delegate. When the viewController is drawing the tableView, it needs to know which cells it's about to draw, so it queries the delegate with a callback method called tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:, and you implement the method by supplying a cell for a given row (given to your method in the form of an indexPath). You might call this returning the state, but you should think more generally. A callback method could theoretically be responsible for anything.

Comment: Thought it works like a delegate, `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is not *technically* a delegate.  It is a part of the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol.  Delegate protocols *typically* are comprised of all optional methods whereas something like a data source protocol has a handful of required methods.   Note that it isn't a hard and fast rule, there are exceptions, and the data source pretty much works just like a delegate anyway.

Comment: you're right, the method i mentioned isn't a delegate method. My mistake. Still, the asker doesn't seem to understand the concept of a delegate, and my example serves the purpose of illustration even if it's not technically accurate.

Comment: Totally;  your comment on your own answer should be integrated into your answer.  Frankly, the UIKit has muddied the definition of "delegate" considerably vs. the AppKit, that and with the addition of `@required` and `@optional`, the differentiation isn't that useful any more.  (`@optional` was explicitly added to allow for things like `NSTableViewDelegate` to be fully declarative).